# How to unit test an @ViewBuilder function?

Tags: swiftui, tdd, viewbuilder

An example function:

```
@ViewBuilder func returnView() -> some View {
        if thisIsTrue == true {
            SomeView()
        } else {
            AnotherView()
        }
    }
```

I've tried testing like this:

```
let testView = sut.returnView()
XCTAssert(testView is SomeView)
```

Which passes when there is only one possible type of view, but then fails as soon as there is a choice.

Any suggestions as to how I can unit test the output of this function?

Comment: `if`/`else` statement is treated by `ViewBuilder` by returning a special type of view to represent conditional content. This view is of type `_ConditionalContent<SomeView, AnotherView>`, which is the opaque type that your function returns as a `some View`

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies things for me. Any idea on how to unit test it?

Comment: Just curious, how are you unit testing the rest of the SwiftUI code (ones that don't involve if / else)?

Comment: Most of it, I’m using UI testing. It’s just I’ve moved a bit of logic from the view to a @ViewBuilder function in my view model. It works, but I’m wondering how to test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The opaque return type `some View` means this function always returns exactly one type on all paths our of the function and that type conforms to `View`, so while it looks like you are returning two different things the ViewBuilder in fact collapses this into a single type that is generic with respect to the real return type.  If you want to know what the opaque type really is you can just have the compiler tell you. For instance here is a playground.  Note that this solution is fragile because changing the implementation of the function very likely will change the return type.

```
import SwiftUI

struct SomeView: View {
  var body: some View { EmptyView() }
}

struct AnotherView: View {
  var body: some View { Color.red}
}

@ViewBuilder func returnView() -> some View {
  if true {
    SomeView()
  } else {
    AnotherView()
  }
}

let a = returnView()

print(type(of: a))
```

output:

```
_ConditionalContent<SomeView, AnotherView>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Yeah, I can test for equality with a string describing the return type, but it's extremely flaky. Marked as answered.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that I went with was to not unit test the output of the function at all.

I created an enum in the view model that had cases that mapped to the different views and then used a computed property of this type to separate the business logic from the view logic.

```
enum ViewType {
  case someView
  case anotherView
}

var viewType: ViewType {
   if thisIsTrue {
      return .someView
   } else {
      return .anotherView
   }
}
```

I can instantiate and test this in my unit testing.

Then in the view itself I created an @ViewBuilder variable and used a switch statement to map it to the view model viewType:

```
@ViewBuilder var view: some View {
   switch viewModel.viewType {
   case .someView:
      SomeView()
   case .anotherView:
      AnotherView()
   }
}
```

I hope this is helpful to someone else.